# Uxexpected indent error while executing multiple if or elif using while loop and multiple break

Tags: python, error-handling, while-loop, indentation, break

I am writing a code that just takes 5 positive values and if the user enters a null or no value it should give an error please do enter a number I keep getting this indention error what are the rules for indentation in python also its not able to evaluate the null or none value and give the error message "please do enter a number", and if I am using elif statement its also the loop should after taking 5 values which is not happening I am new at programming and need your help

```
i=1
while i<5:
 n=int(input("Enter a number  "))
 if n<=0:
     i+=1
     break
print(n)
print("Loop ended , Negative Value Entered")
  if n==None:
     i=1
break
print(n)
print("Loop ended , please do enter a number ")
```

**Here is another code with the elif**

```
i=1
while i<5:
     n=int(input("Enter a number  "))
     if n<=0:
         break
         print(n)
         print("Loop ended , Negative Value Entered")
         i=1
     elif n==None:
             break
             i=1        
             print(n)
             print("Loop ended , please do enter a number ")
     else:
             i+=1
```

Comment: In the second code block, you only need one indentation after `elif n==None:`, currently there are two indentations.

Comment: @Blupper That should not create the issue here. Python generally accepts any number of spaces for indentation as long as it is consistent across a single block of code

Comment: @a_n Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your code is wrong. You cannot have blocks of different indentations without having a statement such as `while`, `for` etc occuring just before it.

This is how you can correct the program, both syntactically and semantically.

```py
i=1
while i<5:
    n=int(input("Enter a number  "))
    if n<=0:
        print("Loop ended , Negative Value Entered")
        break
    if n==None:
        i=1
        print("Loop ended , please do enter a number ")
        break
print(n)
```

Do note: `n` here can never be `None` since python converts it into an integer. If you are trying to catch an "empty input" kind of situation you do not need to worry as python will raise an error and terminate the program if the input is left empty, and hence you wouldn't even need to check for that. Because the line `int(input())` will not accept an empty input string.

Also, in your second snippet, the lines after `break` will not run since `break` terminates the loop immediately, ignoring any statements after it. So you need to give the `break` statements at the end of whatever lines you are executing over there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with both your code blocks:

1. Indentation
2. Code after break. After `break` python will exit the `while` loop and not execute the print statements.

See the code blocks below:

```
i=1
while i<5:
    n=int(input("Enter a number  "))
    if n<=0:
        i+=1
        print(n)
        print("Loop ended , Negative Value Entered")
        break  
    if n==None:
        i=1
        print(n)
        print("Loop ended , please do enter a number ")
        break
```

```
i=1
while i<5:
    n=int(input("Enter a number  "))
    if n<=0:
        print(n)
        print("Loop ended , Negative Value Entered")
        i=1
        break
    elif n==None:
        i=1        
        print(n)
        print("Loop ended , please do enter a number ")
        break
    else:
        i+=1
```